# how to get output by part of data in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table A:
id      code
---------------
1        90
2        85
3        75
```

Table B:

```
id            title
---------------------
902313        reza
854646        matin
755346        amir
602545        martin
105456        ghdsa
```

value in Code filed of table A is part of id of Table B.
i want to get output from Table B(following output) where Table A have part of value of id of table B

```
----output-----
id            title
---------------------
902313        reza
854646        matin
755346        amir
```

another word how to get query on Table B where id of Table B is part of Code of Table A.

Comment: the id field is varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join using **SUBSTR** function.

The substring would give you the following output:

```
SQL> SELECT substr(902313, 1, 2) FROM dual;

SU
--
90

SQL>
```

**Required query:**

```
SELECT b.* 
  FROM table_a a, table_b b
 WHERE TO_CHAR(a.id) = SUBSTR(b.code, 1, 2);
```

Use **TO_CHAR** on id column if it is a **NUMBER** type to avoid any **implicit data type conversion**.